# ClassnotFoundException:Didn't find class "java.util.Base64" on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android

I am facing this while using java.base64 issue `ClassnotFoundException:Didn't find class "java.util.Base64" on path: DexPathList in java.util.Base64`.I want to decrypt the encrypted text.So I am using this code and JAVA 8.Please help me

```
 String encrptedtext = "QW28YjzFVa70mG/o/itYGGoEaV/0EBFY+jnxClcgw=";//secret key that boy given
     byte[] base64decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrptedtext);
    try {

Log.i("EE", "decryptedString---" + new String(base64decodedBytes, "utf-8"));


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What's your java version?

Comment: Java version 8, in android its showing classnotfoundexception.Please give solution

Comment: Have you imported the 'java.util.Base64' in your file?

Comment: Yes i imported the package in android java file

Answer (score -1):

In android, use the `android.util.Base64` class to do the encoding and decoding.

Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

Comment: yes, i tried android.util.base64, now am facing this issue java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64